# How to change FLUTTER DropdownMenuItem's textDirection (change widget direction)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to change widget's textDirection according to the language selection. I have a variable for textDirection in my global translation class and add it to parent widgets. All are work fine except DropdownMenuItems. I tried with wrapping text widget by Directionality widget but still not working as expect. 
Ex: when I change language which use rtl items should align to right which 
is not happening currently.

```
return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Directionality(textDirection: Translations.textDirection ,
                    child: new Text(listItems,textDirection: Translations.textDirection,)

                    ...
```

Also I tried adding textDirection after wrapped whole DropdownButton with a Container.

```
 return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        textDirection: Translations.textDirection,
        children: <Widget>[
          DropdownButton(
```

But still not work. What should I do to change the textDirection of DropdownMenuItems ?? Any help would be appreciate.

note: I can't add textDirection to MaterialApp. Need to change it when select different languages.

Answer (score 11):

[I Solved it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjfPl.png)

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: Text(
                  'City',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Cairo'),
                ),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: dropdownValue,
                elevation: 4,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple, fontFamily: 'Cairo'),
                underline: Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                ),
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue;
                    debugPrint(cityInfo.indexOf(newValue).toString());
                  });
                },
                items:
                    cityInfo.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text(
                        value,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

For left to right text direction:

```
Text('MyText', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,)
```

OR

For right to left text direction:

```
Text('MyText', textDirection: TextDirection.rtl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DropdownButton<String>(
          items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: new Center(
                child: Text(value),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (_) {},
        ),
```

Just wrap the DropDownMenuItem child Widget(Text) with a Center widget

Update: Sorry I miss understood it as how to center the widget.

You can add TextDirection.rtl or TextDirection.ltr to textDirection property

If it does not work try wrapping it a Row with mainAxisAlignment to end

Answer (score 0):

use Directionality widget as aparent of the

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: with all answers this answer is truely the answer